# Create v-expansion-panels from API data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have the below child component called mobReports.vue with v-expansion-panels inside it but they don't show up...

```js
<template>
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel
      v-for="(index, title) in mobReports"
      :key="index"
    >
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        {{ title }}
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content eager>
        <v-card-text>
          {{ index }}
        </v-card-text>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    report: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    mobReports() {
      console.log(this.report)
      if (this.report) {
        console.log('mobReports')
        return this.report
      }
      return {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The REST API call is done in the parent and passed to the child component but the v-for loop doesn't seem to read over the data when the Report Tab is selected.
If I just comment out some code and uncomment allowing Vue to rebuild itself without refreshing the browser it does show up the expansion-panels

Below is the parent and how reports are fetched.

```js
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="mt-0 pt-0">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12" class="pt-2 px-2">
        <v-card min-height="873" class="elevation-0">
          <!-- tab setup -->
          <v-tabs
            v-model="selectedGeneralTab"
            slider-size="4"
          >
            <v-tab href="#tab-analysis">
              Analysis
            </v-tab>

            <v-tab href="#tab-report">
              Report
            </v-tab>

            <v-tabs-items v-model="selectedGeneralTab">
              <v-tab-item
                :key="1"
                :value="'tab-analysis'"
              >
                <!-- Card Body -->
                <v-card-text class="pt-0 px-6">
                  // Analysis Body
                </v-card-text>
              </v-tab-item>

              <!-- REPORT TAB -->
              <v-tab-item
                :key="2"
                :value="'tab-report'"
              >
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-card-title>
                      <div class="headline font-weight-black text--primary">
                        Report
                      </div>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text>
                      <mob-report
                        :report="mobReport"
                      />
                    </v-card-text>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-tab-item>
              <!-- END - REPORT TAB -->
            </v-tabs-items>
          </v-tabs>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>

import { APIService } from '~/api/APIService'
import MobReport from '~/components/mobReport.vue'
const apiService = new APIService()

export default {
  layout: 'default',
  components: {
    MobReport
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedGeneralTab: null,
      mobReport: {},
      loading: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selectedGeneralTab(tabIndex) {
      this.getDataPerSelectedTab(tabIndex)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDataPerSelectedTab(tabIndex) {
      if (tabIndex === 'tab-analysis') {
        this.getAnalysis()
      }
      if (tabIndex === 'tab-report') {
        this.getReport()
      }
    },
    getAnalysis() {
        // Analysis logic
    }
    getReport() {
      apiService
        .getMobReport()
        .then(res => {
          const reportData = res.data
          Object.entries(reportData).forEach(entry => {
            const [key, value] = entry
            Object.assign(this.mobReport, this.mobReport, value)
          })
          return this.mobReport
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false
        })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help on how to get this to render when the Reports Tab is selected would be great

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you get the api object you are using `Object.assign` which [does not trigger reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) so you need to create a fresh object and then assign the new data:

```
getReport() {
      apiService
        .getMobReport()
        .then(res => {
          const reportData = res.data
          const newData = {};
          Object.entries(reportData).forEach(entry => {
            const [key, value] = entry
            Object.assign(newData, value)
          })
          // HERE we are mutating the object and triggering reactivity
          this.mobReport = Object.assign({}, this.mobReport, value)
          return this.mobReport
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false
        })
    },
```

you can also return a function to your computed but with the caveat that it will be executed in every re-render and it won't be cached

```
computed: {
    mobReports: () => {
      console.log(this.report)
      if (this.report) {
        console.log('mobReports')
        return this.report
      }
      return {}
    }
  }
```

also, I don't think you need the intermediary computed in there, you can use the prop directly